# How can I update a parent record by comparing two date fields on parent and child record in Salesforce?

Tags: metadata, data

I have two objects namely Account Record and Purchase Record. My scenario is when I create a new Purchase record, it should check Purchase record field (Purchase.LastSODate) and update the Account record field (Account.LastSODate), when if the Account record is greater than the Purchase record.

So can anyone help me in resolving this issue. When I try updating the record using Process Builder. It shows an error when bulk updated using the integration user

> Error element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate).
>   The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: DUPLICATE_VALUE: Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed). Attempt to update Id more than once in this Api call:.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a limit on the number of updates you can make to the same record in a single batch. Similar issue in this thread: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pHMKQA2

The limit is 12 in each batch of 200.

Workaround for this is to set your batch size lower, likely down to 12 to avoid the issue completely.

A better fix would be to consider an apex solution where you will have more control over what gets updated and when.